# whether Single-shot timer stops automatically?

Tags: timer, embedded, counter, comparator

I'm implementing a Timer 1 (which is basically a comparator & capture timer ) in comparator mode with single-shot mode operation? There's an option for starting the timer in continuous mode too.

My question is when I start the **timer in single shot mode** , after it reaches a mentioned count & compares, it will generate an interrupt flag but then does it mean that the timer is also stopped?

or do I need to **stop it explicitly** in single -shot mode too? I think it makes sense only in continuous mode?

I'm currently checking only the generated interrupt flag & assuming the timer is stopped & clearing the interrupt flag for further operation & the n come out of my function.
however, there is a control bit in the control register of the timer which can be toggled to make it run or stop? Should I just check the bit after the interrupt flag has generated or do I need to reset this control bit too? Which means I should have an explicit function to stop the timer as well?

Additional Information -

I'm using NXP (Philips ) controller.

Thank you in advance,
Prateek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got to read in the NXP datasheet that yes, If any timer, started in single shot (one- shot) mode will stop automatically.

Btw, If any one of you have any explanation kindly, put it below.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To understand microcontroller timers, just have to first realize that there is generally just one single main timer running. When enabled, this timer counts up until it overflows and then starts over.

When you start a "hardware timer", you only set up a register with a timer value which holds the value `main_timer + delay`. The hardware compares this register with the main timer at every tick, and when they match, it triggers an interrupt, sets a port or whatever you have configured it to do. Typically, you'd have to set up your timer register anew after that.

More more specific answers you have to specify the MCU family and part number used. NXP has made everything from ancient 8051 to modern ARM Cortex, and the timer peripheral hardware will be different for every MCU family.